# Pass data to a component with useNavigate from React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `useNavigate` to go to the component and need to pass data (state) to this `ChatRoom` component when I click a button.
The component is on the route `/chatroom`. I'm using React Router Dom `v6`. I have read the documentation but cannot find what I'm looking for.

```js
export default function Home() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate("/chatroom");
  };

  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      className="btn"
      onClick={() => {
        handleClick();
      }}
    >
      Join Chat
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass data to the component that corresponds to `/chatroom` in React Router Dom `v6` like this:

```
navigate('/chatroom', { state: "Hello World!" });
```

And consume it with the help of [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location) hook this way:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
function ChatRoom() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  return (
    <div>
      {state}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Chatroom;
```

If you wanna pass multiple values, use an object, like so:

```
navigate('/chatroom', { state: {id:1, text: "Hello World!"} });
```

And consume it again with  [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location) hook this way:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
function ChatRoom() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  return (
    <div>
      id: {state.id}
      text: {state.text}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Chatroom;
```