# React Router Custom Props array doesnt load, but custom string does

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a ReactTS-App and I pass a prop via Router-Dom-Props to another component. The problem here is that I can use meal.name alone, but if I use meal.food with it or meal.food alone it doesnt work anymore.

```
Uncaught TypeError: meal.food is undefined
```

I checked TypeScript- & useEffect-errors, but I didnt find a solution yet.

And are the props loaded before the first render?

**UPDATE** I can print the meal.food when I use it like that `location.state.meal.food` but I cannot use it from the useState after I set it - I console.log it in the useEffect.

Meal.tsx

```
  return (
    <Link className="Meal Link" to={`/MealDetails/${meal.id}`} state={{ meal: meal }}>
      <div className="MealIconMealName">
        <div className="MealName">{meal.name}</div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

MealDetails.tsx

```
const MealDetails = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const [meal, setMeal] = useState(Object);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.state) {
      if (location.state.meal) {
        setMeal(location.state.meal);
        console.log("useEffect" + meal);
      }
    }
    return () => {};
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div className="MealDetails">
      <header>
        <div className="HeaderText">{meal.name}</div>
      </header>
      <div className="MealDetailsCalorieCounter"></div>
      {meal.food.map((meal : any) => (
        <Food
          key={meal.id}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Example meal-Object out of the .json file

```
    { 
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Breakfast",
      "food": [
        {
            "name": "Waffeln",
            "kcal" : 505
        }
      ],
      "calories": 505
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data to a component with useNavigate from React Router Dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71380596/pass-data-to-a-component-with-usenavigate-from-react-router-dom)

Comment: @yousoumar do you mean that i should pass everything one by one and not in one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is it seems that the `meal.food` is undefined on the initial render prior to the `useEffect` hook updating the local component state from the route state (i.e. from `location.state`).

## Solution

It's considered a React anti-pattern to store passed data and/or derived "state" in local component state. Just consume the passed `location.state.meal` route state directly. You should also use defensive programming patterns in case a user navigates to the route rendering `MealDetails` from anywhere else *other than* the link that passes the route state.

Example:

```
const MealDetails = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation(); // <-- access state
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const meal = state || {}; // <-- provide fallback value

  return (
    <div className="MealDetails">
      <header>
        <div className="HeaderText">{meal.name}</div>
      </header>
      <div className="MealDetailsCalorieCounter"></div>
      {(meal.food }} []).map((meal: any) => ( // <-- provide fallback array
        <Food key={meal.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think useEffect here is necessary. You can get the meal directly from the location object.

```
const MealDetails = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { meal } = location.state;
  return (
    <div className="MealDetails">
      <header>
        <div className="HeaderText">{meal.name}</div>
      </header>
      <div className="MealDetailsCalorieCounter"></div>
      {meal.food.map((meal : any) => (
        <Food
          key={meal.id}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It works, but shouldnt I use useState for variables like that in React and I dont have a guard then too. Is this a problem?