# React + Redux: Data not being passed correctly components with dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm fetching 3 different endpoints from my backend. My goal is to display all the data. I need to pass this data to the correct components, however I am using dynamic routes.

My error is that my data comes to artists.js as an empty array.

I have tried:

Using useNavigate to pass the data [link to previous SOF question, user suggested redux toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019401/issues-passing-data-to-components-using-usenavigate)

Using Link to pass the data.

Using redux toolkit to pass the data. I am new to Redux, so it's possible I have done something wrong in my code.

I believe it's a timing, rendering cycle error. However I am not sure how to fix it. When I put in some conditional rendering in the artists component, it showed me the correct data in the console logs on it's second render. But now I am not sure what to do from there. It is stuck with the page saying "loading". I tried mapping the data after the conditional rendering (where `return <div>Loading...</div>;` is), but on page refresh, all the rendered data disappears from the page.

here is the code from top to bottom:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Genres from "./Components/Genres"
import TopTracks from "./Components/TopTracks"
import Results from "./Components/Results"
import { Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Genres />} />
      <Route path='/:genre' element={<Results />} />
      <Route path='/:artist' element={<TopTracks />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

genres.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setData } from '../redux/spotifyDataSlice';

function Genres() {
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/genres/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setGenres(data.genres))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  function handleClick(genre) {
    const query_params = {
      genre: genre
    };
  
    Promise.all([
      fetch("/api/artists/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": "",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(query_params),
      }),
      fetch("/api/playlists/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": "",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(query_params),
      }),
      fetch("/api/tracks/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": "",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(query_params),
      })
    ])
      .then((responses) => Promise.all(responses.map((response) => response.json())))
      .then(([artists, playlists, tracks]) => {
        dispatch(setData({ artists, playlists, tracks }));
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="genre-list-container">
        <ul className="genre-list">
          {genres.map((genre) => (
            <li className="genre" key={genre}>
              <Link to={`/${genre}`} onClick={() => handleClick(genre)}>{genre}</Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Genres;
```

results.js

```
import React from "react";
import Artists from "./Artists";
import Playlists from "./Playlists";
import Tracks from "./Tracks";

function Results() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Artists />
      <Playlists />
      <Tracks />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Results;
```

artists.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function Artists() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const artists = useSelector((state) => state.spotifyData.artists);
  console.log(artists)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  if (isLoading) {
    if (artists.length === 0) {
      return <div>No artists found</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  }

  function handleClick(artist) {
    fetch("/api/top_tracks/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": "",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ artist_id: artist.id }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        navigate(`/${artist.name}`, { state: { data } });
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Artists:</div>
      {artists.map((artist) => (
        <div key={artist.id}>
          <img src={artist.image_url} alt={artist.name} />
          <h1 onClick={() => handleClick(artist)}>{artist.name}</h1>
          <p>Popularity: {artist.popularity}</p>
          <p>Genres: {artist.genres}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Artists;
```

spotifyDataSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const spotifyDataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'spotifyData',
  initialState: {
    artists: [],
    playlists: [],
    tracks: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setData(state, action) {
      const { artists, playlists, tracks } = action.payload;
      console.log("Artists:", artists);
      console.log("Playlists:", playlists);
      console.log("Tracks:", tracks);
      state.artists = artists;
      state.playlists = playlists;
      state.tracks = tracks;
    },
  },
});

export const { setData } = spotifyDataSlice.actions;
export default spotifyDataSlice.reducer;
```

store.js:

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import spotifyDataReducer from './spotifyDataSlice';

const loggerMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  console.log('Dispatching:', action);
  const result = next(action);
  console.log('Next State:', store.getState());
  return result;
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    spotifyData: spotifyDataReducer,
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware().concat(loggerMiddleware)
});

export default store;
```

edit:
Here are some examples of my POST responses.

```
{artists: {…}, playlists: {…}, tracks: {…}}
```

artists:

```
artists: {total: 13, artists: Array(13)}
```

example of artists object:

```
{name: 'Aborted', id: '1XRhUgCyzIdeT8d9KMfeDR', image_url: 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5eb457a41afcb20ec257fce22d4', popularity: 39, genres: Array(8)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to manage any data loading state from the `Results` or children pages, I'd recommend actually leveraging redux-toolkit more by moving all the fetching logic into an asynchronous action that can have its loading status incorporated right into the state.

Example:

spotifyDataSlice.js

Create a Thunk function to handle the fetching, and update the state slice to include a loading state that is updated when the asynchronous action is pending and settles.

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk(
  'spotifyData/fetchData',
  async (genre, thunkAPI) => {
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": "",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ genre }),
    };
  
    try {
      const requests = ["artists", "playlists", "tracks"]
        .map(key => fetch(`/api/${key}/`, options)
          .then(response => response.json())
          // access response property, e.g. data.artists, data.playlists, etc
          .then(data => data[key])
        );

      const [artists, playlists, tracks] = await Promise.all(requests);
      return { artists, playlists, tracks };
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
    
  }
);

const spotifyDataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'spotifyData',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    artists: [],
    playlists: [],
    tracks: [],
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchData.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(fetchData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.artists = action.payload.artists;
        state.playlists = action.payload.playlists;
        state.tracks = action.payload.tracks;
      })
      .addCase(fetchData.rejected, (state) => {
        state.loading = false;
      });
    },
  },
});

export default spotifyDataSlice.reducer;
```

genres.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from '../redux/spotifyDataSlice';

function Genres() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/genres/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setGenres(data.genres))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => genre => {
    dispatch(fetchData(genre));
  }

  return (
    <div className="genre-list-container">
      <ul className="genre-list">
        {genres.map((genre) => (
          <li className="genre" key={genre}>
            <Link to={`/${genre}`} onClick={handleClick(genre)}>
              {genre}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Genres;
```

results.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Artists from "./Artists";
import Playlists from "./Playlists";
import Tracks from "./Tracks";

function Results() {
  const isLoading = useSelector(state => state.spotifyData.loading);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading
        ? <div>Loading...</div>
        : (
          <>
            <Artists />
            <Playlists />
            <Tracks />
          </>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Results;
```

artists.jsx (*`Playlists` and `Tracks` components get same treatment*)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function Artists() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const artists = useSelector(state => state.spotifyData.artists);

  function handleClick(artist) {
    ....
  }

  if (!artists.length) {
    return <div>No artists found</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Artists:</div>
      {artists.map((artist) => (
        <div key={artist.id}>
          <img src={artist.image_url} alt={artist.name} />
          <h1 onClick={() => handleClick(artist)}>{artist.name}</h1>
          <p>Popularity: {artist.popularity}</p>
          <p>Genres: {artist.genres}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Artists;
```

> but on page refresh, all the rendered data disappears from the page

Redux is in-memory state management, when the page is reloaded, the memory from the previous instance is dumped. The typical solution is to persist your redux store to localStorage or anything more longterm. [Redux Persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) is a great common solution for this and is easy to integrate.

As a stop-gap you could simply move the fetching logic to the `"/:genres"` route so that when the page is reloaded and `Results` is mounted it will simply trigger a refetch.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Genres() {
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/genres/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setGenres(data.genres))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="genre-list-container">
      <ul className="genre-list">
        {genres.map((genre) => (
          <li className="genre" key={genre}>
            <Link to={`/${genre}`}>
              {genre}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Genres;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Artists from "./Artists";
import Playlists from "./Playlists";
import Tracks from "./Tracks";
import { fetchData } from '../redux/spotifyDataSlice';

function Results() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { genre } = useParams();

  const isLoading = useSelector(state => state.spotifyData.loading);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // fetch data on component mount or when genre value changes
    dispatch(fetchData(genre));
  }, [dispatch, genre]);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading
        ? <div>Loading...</div>
        : (
          <>
            <Artists />
            <Playlists />
            <Tracks />
          </>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Results;
```

Comment: I've implemented your code as shown, and I opted to move the fetch to the genres route. But, I get "no artists found". The data still comes in as an empty array with a console log of artists, but I can see with a console log that the data does populate on the second pass of the console.log.

Comment: @Scottsdaaale Are you saying that even though the data is fetched, the UI doesn't ever render it? Where/how are you console logging the selected state? And this is all after the `isLoading` state completes after the data is fetched?

Comment: In Artists.jsx, I have: `const artists = useSelector(state => state.spotifyData.artists);
  console.log(artists)` localhost render shows the conditional "no artists found". console log shows `[]` then shows {total: 33, artists: Array(33)}. If I do `const artists = useSelector(state => state.spotifyData.artists.artists);
  console.log(artists)` I get error reading `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'artists')`

Comment: @Scottsdaaale Seems you possibly either *didn't* unpack an `artists` property from a response object when updating state, or nested unnecessarily another `artists` property under `state.spotifyData.artists` when updating state. I can't see what your POST responses look like to verify what should be correct though, just basing my answer on the code you provided. Can you update your post with example responses?

Comment: I console logged the promise.all data `const [artists, playlists, tracks] = await Promise.all(requests); console.log({ artists, playlists, tracks });` and added it to my question.

Comment: @Scottsdaaale I see. It seems it's the first case where the the response value you want to store into state is the nested property, e.g. `artists.artists`, `playlists.playlists`, and `tracks.tracks`. I've updated my answer to do the "unpacking" in the `fetch` Promise chain.

Comment: @Scottsdaaale Certainly, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is to refactor your code as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76078197/12737879) below (*I also have bookmarked it*).

However, I will answer your unexpected behavior:

> ...it showed me the correct data in the console logs on it's second render. But now I am not sure what to do from there. It is stuck with the page saying "loading".

The reason it seem "stuck" at "Loading" is that inside *artists.js* you are never updating the `isLoading` state to `false`, so `isLoading` is ***always*** `true`.

The issue with the condition:

```js
if (isLoading) {
    if (artists.length === 0) {
      return <div>No artists found</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  }
```

Is saying: *if `isLoading` is `true` then check if `artists.length === 0`*: on the initial render it is `true` so it correctly shows the message "No artists found", *but* the issue is that `isLoading` is ***always*** `true` and when `artists`'s length is not `0` meaning it contains at least 1 item, the condition says: *`isLoading` is `true` and `artists.length` is not `0`*: so it correctly returns "Loading" (*even* when there's data inside `artists`).

But as-is in your case you may not want to return "Loading" in *artists.js* since the condition is '`artists`'s length' which on initial render (*when component mounts*) has a length of `0` -> is an empty array (`[]`).

However, the "Loading" could still be used when making a fetch call like your `handleClick` does (*but also parent component `Results` will use the "Loading" if you set up the code like in the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76078197/12737879), which is a far better choice*), so the final code of *artists.js* would look like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function Artists() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const artists = useSelector((state) => state.spotifyData.artists);
  console.log(artists)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); // modified initial state: false

  function handleClick(artist) {
    setIsLoading(true); // start Loading before the fetch call
    fetch("/api/top_tracks/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": "",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ artist_id: artist.id }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        navigate(`/${artist.name}`, { state: { data } });
        setIsLoading(false); // stop Loading once data is received
      });
  }

  if (isLoading) {
   return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
     {artists.length === 0 ? <div>No artists found</div> : (
     <>
      <div>Artists:</div>
      {artists.map((artist) => (
        <div key={artist.id}>
          <img src={artist.image_url} alt={artist.name} />
          <h1 onClick={() => handleClick(artist)}>{artist.name}</h1>
          <p>Popularity: {artist.popularity}</p>
          <p>Genres: {artist.genres}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
     </>
     )
    </div>
  );
}
export default Artists;
```